# If $\mid\Omega_E\mid \geq 2$ then there are at least two vertices $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega_E$ with $\text{deg}(\alpha)=\text{deg}(\beta)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Proof the following: Let $\Omega=(\Omega_E,\Omega_K)$ be a (simple) graph. If $\mid\Omega_E\mid \geq 2$ then there are at least two vertices $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega_E$ with $\text{deg}(\alpha)=\text{deg}(\beta)$.

Definitions and additional information:

A graph is a pair $G = (V, E)$, where $V$ is a set whose elements are called vertices, and $E$ is a set of paired vertices, whose elements are called edges.

The edges of a graph define a symmetric relation on the vertices, called the adjacency relation. Specifically, two vertices $x$ and $y$ are adjacent if $\{x, y\}$ is an edge. A graph may be fully specified by its adjacency matrix $A$, which is an $n \times n$ square matrix, with $A_{ij}$ specifying the number of connections from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. For a simple graph, $A_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$, indicating disconnection or connection respectively, meanwhile $A_{ii}=0$.

I'm currently learning for my upcoming discrete maths exam and found this old exam question. Unfortunately, I really don't know how solve the question. Thanks in advance!

If $\mid\Omega_E\mid \geq 2$ then there are at least two vertices $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega_E$ with $\text{deg}(\alpha)=\text{deg}(\beta)$.

Comment: If the graph is simple, then the degree is bounded by $n-1$, but you have $n$ points, thus we are done by the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: Actually, one needs to distinguish the case where some point has degree $0$. Then the rest of the graph is still simple and has either a degree $0$ (then we are done) or we can use the argument in my previous comment (pigeon hole principle as the degree now is in $\{ 1, \dots, n-2\}$ and we have $n-1$ points).